# Light fixture problem

Tags: electrical, light, fans

[image]

Just got a new house. This is how the old fixture was wired. The light worked but the fan didn’t. Attempted to wire up a new fixture. Nutted the white from the fixture to the other 3 whites coming out of the box. And nutted the black from the fixture to the blue coming out of the box, which I traced back to the switch. But I flipped the switch and nothing. What did I do wrong?[image]

The location is Chicago and the wiring is in conduit.

Comment: The red and white to the left were as shown, nutted to isolate and not connected to anything?

Comment: That is correct, as far as I know. I can double check tomorrow, but I’m pretty sure there is no power to the isolated red wire with all the breakers on.